# What are some ways to clean up async code to be more readable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

This code does multi-level page scraping, one function creates the original scraped list of URLs, and the other loops through those and gathers all links from those pages and stores those in an array. My last function loops through these results and pushes them to my results object and then creates a data file from the results. My question is how can I make this code better?

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

let URL = 'https://toscrape.com';
let results = {
  sites: [],
};

// grabs all urls from original link and returns array
const getURLS = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(URL);
    const data = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const urlQueue = [];

    // finds all absolute links and pushs to urlQueue array
    $("a[href^='http']").each((i, elem) => {
      const link = $(elem).attr('href');
      //checks to make sure link isnt any duplicate links in urlqueue array
      unique(link, urlQueue);
    });
    return urlQueue;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
  }
};

// takes array from getURLs and loops those, scraping each site in a queue fashion
const getSubURLs = async () => {
  let urls = await getURLS();
  siteList = [];

  try {
    for (const url of urls) {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      const data = res.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);

      //create sites object and links array that will go inside object
      let sites = {};
      sites.url = url;
      let links = [];
      $("a[href^='/']").each((i, elem) => {
        let link = $(elem).attr('href');
        unique(link, links, url);
        sites.links = links;
      });
      siteList.push(sites);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
  }
  return siteList;
};

const exportResults = async () => {
  //call function and push results to json
  let urls = await getSubURLs();
  //loop through urls and push to results object
  for (const url of urls) {
    results.sites.push(url);
  }
  //create JSON file and
  fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 4), function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('complete');
  });
};

function unique(url, arr, baseURL) {
  if (arguments.length < 3) {
    baseURL = '';
  } else {
    baseURL;
  }
  if (arr.indexOf(url) === -1) {
    arr.push(baseURL + url);
  }
}

exportResults();
```

Comment: you have repeting logic inside your try-catch blocks which could (should) be extracted to a function which will be called inside those blocks

Comment: Define "better"? The obvious improvement (code wise) is to make `getURLs` recursive

Comment: how would i make get urls recursive?

Comment: If this is working code, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for "code improvement" questions.  Please be sure and follow the proper procedure for posting questions there as they have a specific way of doing things.

Comment: thank you, sorry, I'm pretty new here

Comment: Don't use global variables, pass values by argument (`await exportResults(await getSubURLs(await getURLs()))`), abstract out logic for loading a page and finding links, handle errors properly, use `fs.promises` instead of callbacks, make `unique` less weird (or at least give it a more descriptive name), use default argument values.